# How to know when the window zorder changes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

Looking for a way to be notified when any windows ZOrder changes?

Zorder refers to the layering of the windows. a zorder of 0 is at the bottom. I don't know any other way to ask this question.

This would be for Windows XP or newer, using .NET, c# OR vb.net.

Comment: It's tagged with Windows and .NET so I assume he asks the question in the context of Windows desktop programming for the .NET platform. However, the question could have been formed much better, I agree.

Comment: Instead of bashing the question, how about helping me explain it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently windows will send a [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632653(VS.85).aspx) when your window moves/resizes/swaps z order. Combine this with `GetTopWindow` and `GetNextWindow` to work out what the current order of the windows are, and you should be able to work out where all the windows are in your app. [825595](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825595/how-to-get-the-zorder-in-windows) has the details about those two API calls. [798295](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798295/how-can-i-use-getnextwindow-in-c) has more info about `GetNextWindow`.

**edit** *even though this is already accepted...*

And, for anyone finding this via google, [932988](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932988/c-form-control-move) has info about how to capture these messages using `WndProc`. I hate to leave a question not fully answered :-)

Comment: I guess it was not that cryptic. Thanks.

Comment: Naw, it was OK after the edit. Looks like it might have been a bit light on for info before the edit though :-) It struck me as an interesting question though